# How to make the bold $\mathbf{A}$ under beamer the same as under article？

Tags: beamer, fonts, article

The bold under beamer looks thicker and doesn't quite match other normal characters, like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        A$\mathbf{A}$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: f1]
And the boldface under article looks to match other normal characters, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
    A$\mathbf{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image: f2]

What should I do to make the font in beamer mode the same as in the article？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[...]
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
[...]
```